# elementtree - get title?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
<item rdf:about="http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0005">    
<title>CVE-2014-0005</title>
<link>http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-0005</link>
<description>PicketBox and JBossSX, as used in Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform (JBEAP) 6.2.2 and JBoss BRMS before 6.0.3 roll up patch 2, allows remote authenticated users to read and modify the application sever configuration and state by deploying a crafted application.</description>
<dc:date>2015-02-20T16:59:00Z</dc:date>
</item>
<item rdf:about="http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-1831">
<title>CVE-2014-1831 (passenger)</title>
<link>http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-1831</link>
<description>Phusion Passenger before 4.0.37 allows local users to write to certain files and directories via a symlink attack on (1) control_process.pid or a (2) generation-* file.</description>
<dc:date>2015-02-19T15:59:02Z</dc:date>
</item>
```

Hi,

Given the above, I am trying to extract the text value from the title item out of an xml file.  However the below isn't working (am getting no results).  Please advise.

```
def processxml():
    tree = ET.parse('nvd-rss.xml')
    for item in tree.findall( 'item/title' ):
        print (title.text)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm nowhere close to an XML expert, so this question might be plain wrong, but isn't that XML missing a _root_ tag? (one single tag that involves all the `<item>` nodes?) I'm just trying to confirm, so I can have a working example.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's going on: You're putting your _title_ nodes into a variable called `item`, but you're trying to print `title.text` (and at that point, `item` already contains the `<title>CVE-2014-0005</title>` node. Try `print (item.text)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As BorrajaX mentioned you need to change your code in the for loop to `print(item.text)`, because you iterate through all tags ('elements') the `findall()` -method of ElementTree-module returns. You can get the text inside an element by reading the attribute `text` of an ElementTree element instance.

```
# create an ElementTree instance called tree

for element in tree.findall( 'item/title' ):
    print(element.text)
```

Some other attributes of an ElementTree element instance:

- `.tag` Name of the element
- `.text` Text inside the element
- `.tail` Text following the element
- `.attrib` Dictionary containing all element's attribute names and their corresponding values

Comment: The `tree` line under the with statement is under-indented. Also, you can just pass the file's path to `ElementTree.parse`, as the OP is doing: `tree = ElementTree.parse('nvd-rss.xml')` will work.

Comment: Thank's! You are right The `parse()` function needs a source argument, which is either **the name of the file** or **a file object** containing the XML code.